# Game in google earth plugin crashes occasionally

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I have created a little flight simulator based on milktruck demo. The problem is that the plugin crashes every couple of refreshes. I have no idea why that is. It happens on all browsers

You can see the game here
http://www.stepupforisrael.com/plane-game/0205/Mingame.htm

Any clue will be welcome....

Comment: that link doesn't seem to point to an implementation of the plugin. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: sorry. now it's the right link

Answer (score 1):

I see, the issue is that after a few refreshes you get the error  `ERR_BRIDGE_OTHER_SIDE_PROBLEM` and the detail is `bad status`

I believe this is a bug with how you are loading the plug-in itself - I can reproduce it using a very basic set up. Also, It looks as if there is already a bug report for it here.

http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=736

Form reading around, and testing, it appears that loading the plug-in using the Google Loader resolves the issue. To do this.

Firstly, remove the onload 'init' call from the body element.

So that

`<body onload='init();' onunload="//GUnload()">`

becomes

`<body onunload="GUnload()">`

Then use the Google loader callback to handle the initialization. To do that place this line at the end of your script block, right before the closing  element.

`google.setOnLoadCallback(init);`

My thinking is that the onload event occurs immediately after a page is loaded. However, sometimes the plugin has not finished authentication when this event occurs, hence the intermittent error. You can read more about this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-earth-browser-plugin/vvXKanCJbJU

Comment: I've tried over and over and it doesn't appear that this solved it... but thanks anyway. i will not continue developing in GE for now.

Answer (score 0):

We had our own piece of pain with that error and we used solution described in a different answer (GUnload etc) - without success. The problem was solved when we moved our code from some murky hosting we used - to Amazon EC2. The error stopped immediately. Was it caused by a timeout between our original host and Google servers? We don't know anything except what we did saved us...